# TypeError:'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pyexcelerator

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import MySQLdb
import os,sys
import time
import datetime
from pyExcelerator import *

def main():
    '''get datas from mysql to excel'''
    w=Workbook()
    ws=w.add_sheet('user')

    mysql_conn=MySQLdb.connect(................,charset="utf8")
    cursor=mysql_conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("select * from students")
    results=cursor.fetchall() 
    results_count=len(results)
    cursor.close()
    mysql_conn.close()  
    a=results_count-1
    print a
    #print results

    row=0     
    for r in results:        
        r3=[(x[0:2],x[2],x[3:]) for x in r]
        w3=datetime.strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
        [ws.write(x[0:2],i) for i in r3]

        [ws.write(w3,i) for i in r3]
        [ws.write(x[3:],i or '') for i in r3]:       
        row+=1  
    w.save('data.xls')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want get data from mysql to excel ,but 
`r3=[(x[0:2],x[2],x[3:]) for x in r]` gives me  `TypeError:'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable`.

I do not know how to about it, and I just study only 3 week, please help me?

Answer (score 7):

`x` is a `datetime.datetime` object which cannot be use with the [] notation as in `x[0:2]`.

It means that one of your columns holds a date object which must be parsed differently.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't want to be using pyExcelerator - it's old and hasn't been updated in 3 odd years (and has been superseded).

What you should be using is the utilities at http://www.python-excel.org/ and this provides functions for working with datetimes. Excel stores these as floats since a certain epoch. For info https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html - under the section "Dates in Excel spreadsheets". Also see https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#xldate.xldate_as_tuple-function for how to convert an excel representation of a date to a standard python datetime.

If you easy_install/pip xlutils, you'll get both the xlrd (reading) and xlwt (writing) libraries. Up to version 2003 files are supported, but 2007+ (.xlsx file) support is close to coming out of beta.

**edit**

Forgot to mention that https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html describes how the xlwt library can take a `datetime.dateime` and convert that to an Excel cell.

Comment: You also need to set a `XFStyle()` style object when writing the cell; `style = XFStyle(); style.num_format = "YYYY-MM-DD"` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

One of the fields in your table seems to contain `datetime` objects, `MySQLdb` also returns them as `datetime`. You probably want to convert `datetime` to `str` first. That line seems to take some part of the `datetime` by using slices. You could achieve the same with [`datetime.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).